# CSS url relative path -- how do I go backwards?

Tags: css

say I have a css folder and a pictures folder, all contained within the parent directory. In the css folder I have a css file in which I want to use `background-image:url()`

What would I put as the file location if I'm attempting to access a picture inside the pictures folder? I currently have `background-image: url('/.../pic/windowtopbg.png');` but that fails to show the background image.

Answer (score 7):

It's 2 periods like `../`:

```
background-image: url('../pic/windowtopbg.png');
```

every `../` goes up one folder, so if you have your folders like:

```
[Main Folder] |-> CSS -> Mainstyle.css
       =      |-> IMAGES -> Puppy.jpg
```

And you wanted to access a image in the image folder like:

```
[Main Folder] -> IMAGES -> Puppy.jpg
```

You are going up one folder to the main folder so you use one `../`:

```
background-image: url('../IMAGES/Puppy.jpg');
```